# Unable to use Windows Application Package when the app references Windows.winmd

Tags: uwp, desktop-bridge

I tried to use the new method of creating Appx packages, Windows Application Package project using Visual Studio 2017. The main (WPF) project uses UWP api by referencing Windows.winmd as suggested [here](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/01/25/calling-windows-10-apis-desktop-application/).

```
<Reference Include="Windows, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.16299.0\Windows.winmd</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

The main project compiles fine as before, but when I attempt to create the appx package from the Windows Application Package project, I get a warning and thousands of similar errors as below:

> No implementation file was provided for the .winmd file
>   '[ApplicationOutputDirectory]\Windows.winmd'. To generate registration
>   information in the app manifest, specify the 'Implementation' metadata
>   on the .winmd reference item in the project file.
>
> The .winmd file 'Windows.winmd' contains type
>   'Windows.Storage.IKnownFoldersStatics2'. The use of the Windows
>   namespace is reserved.
>
> The .winmd file 'Windows.winmd' contains type
>   'Windows.Storage.NameCollisionOption'. The use of the Windows namespace is reserved.

Is there another way to add a reference to UWP in a WPF app to avoid this issue?

Comment: Official docs are here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-enhance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you set "Copy Local to false for this reference. You only need it at build time, you won't need the .winmd file packaged up into the .appx package.